# Download .xls File from URL with authentication

Tags: android, file, authentication, download, xls

I am trying to download an excel file from a website with authentication. Usually if i manually copy the link to a web browser there is a pop up window that would say File.xls Save or Cancel. Not sure how to be able to download this file programmatically via Android.

I just can't seem to get it to work. I was able to download an Excel file from the link but when I open the file its unsupported. I realized I was just creating the file and that I needed to be logged in to be able to download the file.

So first problem I tried to use the following code for authentication and I'm not even sure if I'm logged in or it worked;

```
public void CheckAuthenticate(){

    try {
        // Sets the authenticator that will be used by the networking code
        // when a proxy or an HTTP server asks for authentication.
        Authenticator.setDefault(new CustomAuthenticator());
        URL url = new URL("http://*****.com/account/login");
        // read text returned by server
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(line);
        }
        in.close();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println("Malformed URL: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("I/O Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static class CustomAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    // Called when password authorization is needed
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        // Get information about the request
        String prompt = getRequestingPrompt();
        String hostname = getRequestingHost();
        InetAddress ipaddr = getRequestingSite();
        int port = getRequestingPort();
        String email = "XXXXXXX";
        String password = "XXXXXXX";

        System.out.println("prompt: " + prompt);
        System.out.println("hostname: " + hostname);
        System.out.println("requesting site: " + ipaddr);

        // Return the information (a data holder that is used by Authenticator)
        return new PasswordAuthentication(email, password.toCharArray());

    }
}
```

The second issue is that I am not sure if I'm doing the following code correctly:

```
 URL url = new URL(downloadUrl);//Create Download URl
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();//Open Url Connection
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");//Set Request Method to "GET" since we are grtting data
            c.connect();//connect the URL Connection
```

Comment: Are you sure the server supports BASIC http authentication? What a software is used on the server-side?

Comment: Whats the link ?

Comment: I am not sure what is the the software on the server side but its a booking website.

Comment: Well I just checked and saved the website password and downloaded the file and the file downloaded was unsupported. I think i am still having an issue with downloading a file.